# Treetop ruby parser - could not parse Ordered Choice

Tags: ruby, rubygems, treetop, peg

I have defined simple grammar for parsing string and number using Treetop as below.

```
grammar Simple
    rule value
        number / string
    end 

    rule string
        word space string
        /
        word
    end

    rule word
        [0-9a-zA-Z]+
    end

    rule number
        [1-9] [0-9]*
    end

    rule space
        ' '+
    end
end
```

Ruby:

```
parser = SimpleParser.new
parser.parse('123abc wer') # => nil
```

I expect the parser to return **string node** but look like the parser **could not understand** the input. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Treetop (and PEGs in general, actually) the choice operator is *ordered*, unlike most other parsing formalisms.

So, in

```
rule value
  number / string
end
```

you are telling Treetop that you *prefer* `number` over `string`.

Your input starts with `1`, which matches *both* `number` and `string` (through `word`), but you told Treetop to prefer the `number` interpretation, so it parses it as a `number`. When it comes to the `a` in the input, it has no more rules to apply, and thus it returns nothing (`nil`), because in Treetop it is an error to not consume the entire input stream.

If you simply reverse the order of the choice, the entire input will interpreted as a `string` instead of a `number`:

```
SyntaxNode+String0 offset=0, "123abc wer" (word,space,string):
  SyntaxNode offset=0, "123abc":
    SyntaxNode offset=0, "1"
    SyntaxNode offset=1, "2"
    SyntaxNode offset=2, "3"
    SyntaxNode offset=3, "a"
    SyntaxNode offset=4, "b"
    SyntaxNode offset=5, "c"
  SyntaxNode offset=6, " ":
    SyntaxNode offset=6, " "
  SyntaxNode offset=7, "wer":
    SyntaxNode offset=7, "w"
    SyntaxNode offset=8, "e"
    SyntaxNode offset=9, "r"
```

Or, you could keep the order as it is, but allow the `value` rule to be matched multiple times. Either insert a new top-level rule like this:

```
rule values
  value+
end
```

or modify the `value` rule like this:

```
rule value
  (number / string)+
end
```

Which will give you an AST roughly like this:

```
SyntaxNode offset=0, "123abc wer":
  SyntaxNode+Number0 offset=0, "123":
    SyntaxNode offset=0, "1"
    SyntaxNode offset=1, "23":
      SyntaxNode offset=1, "2"
      SyntaxNode offset=2, "3"
      SyntaxNode+String0 offset=3, "abc wer" (word,space,string):
        SyntaxNode offset=3, "abc":
          SyntaxNode offset=3, "a"
          SyntaxNode offset=4, "b"
      SyntaxNode offset=5, "c"
    SyntaxNode offset=6, " ":
      SyntaxNode offset=6, " "
    SyntaxNode offset=7, "wer":
      SyntaxNode offset=7, "w"
      SyntaxNode offset=8, "e"
      SyntaxNode offset=9, "r"
```

Comment: Thanks Jörg, 
Yes you are correct. I prefer to match number to string in the value rule. And how could I "allow the value rule to be matched multiple times"? To get the above example working.

Comment: @mann: The repetition operators in Treetop are `+` and `*` with similar meaning as they have in `Regexp`. See the edit for details.

Comment: @Clifford on Treetop Development google group suggest to use "!." to match EOF, so after changing the number rule to "[1-9] [0-9] !." now I can match both number and string perfectly. thanks Jörg!